# iOS разработка на Windows

Tags: ios, unity3d, xcode, xamarin, flutter

Знаю что уже не раз был задан этот вопрос как же разрабатывать приложение или игры iOS не имея никакой продукции Apple. Но проблема в том что эта информация которую я находил была за 2017-2018 годы, а сейчас уже вторая половина 2019.

Меня интересуют вот эти вопросы:

1. Читал много о кросс-платформенных площадках для программирование типа Fluter, [Xamarin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9cOCEuuEOE) или [Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706852/developing-unity-game-on-windows-for-ios-devices) но некоторые статьи противоречат друг другу одни пишут что можно другие пишут что нет. Вопрос на да или нет. **Есть ли платформа на которой можно делать приложение как на Android так и iOS только на Windows?**
2. Читал ещё об том что можно загрузить виртуальную машину с ОС MacOS и загрузить на неё XCode и писать приложение. **На сколько это удобно и точно не нужно для этого любого реального устройства Apple?**
3. **Есть ли конвертер Android приложения на iOS?**
4. **И если на предвещающие 2 вопроса ответ нет то посоветуйте Apple компьютер на котором удобно будет идти XCode по минимальной цене б/у.**

P.S.: Вы меня тоже поймите не у всех есть возможность купить себе MacBook или Mac Mini. Просто ищу реальный способ написать приложение на iOS. Ещё Apple до этой поры поддерживает iPhone 5s который стоит 100$ вот из-за этого и теряется все моя целевая аудитория.

Поделитесь новостями или дайте совет что делать?

Comment: А в чем такая надобность написать приложение именно на iOS? Из всего перечисленного работаю с Unity - это точно не то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я хочу писать и игры и приложение на Windows для iOS ищу бесплатный способ как это сделать? Поделитесь информацией если вы её владеете.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я написал приложение для студентов мед ВУЗов оно охватило большую часть все студентов которые имеют устройство Android но большой Хейт идет от владельцев iPhone. Они не понимают что нужно платить большие деньги чтобы написать приложение на iOS.  100$ в год я ещё могу заплатить но позволить себе MacBook даже б/у сейчас я не могу. На данный момент я располагаю относительно средним ноутбуком. По этому ищу способ что бы выйти на iOS.

Comment: Я уже сказал, работаю только с юнити и это не то, что вам нужно для **приложений**, для игр он подойдет, однако все равно нужна macOS и айфон/айпад для разработки. По остальным вопросам, увы, помочь не могу.

Answer (score 2):

1. Для загрузки приложения в App Store его необходимо собрать и подписать на компьютере под управлением macOS. Перечисленные вами средства разработки (Unity, Flutter и т.п.) позволяют писать на Windows единый код для Android и iOS, но не позволяют сделать на Windows сборку и подпись – то есть приложение вы не сможете загрузить в App Store. Единственный способ с этим бороться, помимо покупки компьютера Apple – локальные виртуальные машины и сервисы по онлайн-аренде виртуальных машин специально для разработчиков.
2. Это крайне неудобно на средних по производительности ПК. Любого реального устройства Apple не требуется, однако установка виртуальной машины может нарушать лицензию на macOS.
3. Не слышал о таких.
4. Xcode 11 установится на любом компьютере с поддержкой macOS 10.14. Самый дешевый из них – Mac Mini (Late 2012), на Авито можно найти начиная с 20-25 тыс. ₽. Однако я рекомендую купить компьютер посовременнее и подороже, иначе виртуалка может с высокой вероятностью оказаться быстрее.